# Can I leave an air hockey table on for shabbos and use it?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

If I leave an air hockey table on from before the sabbath, would it be permissible to use it?

Comment: Why is it worse than a fan?

Comment: Do you have any particular concern? Does it make noise?

Comment: I can’t seem to find anything wrong with it it just feels like there is something wrong with it. Do you know what I mean? Just imagine playing air hockey on shabbos. It seems strange

Comment: Sounds like you are making the *uvda d'chol* argument.

Comment: If the issue is uvda d’chol then it’s related to the playing  of the game, not the air blowing.

Comment: @kugelman, you seem to be touching on, and indeed bothered by, the issur of uvdin d'chol. The very fact that if "feels wrong" is a good indication that it might fall under this prohibition, although given the unclear exact parameters of this issur, it's hard to rule on specifics without being a real posek.

Answer (score 3):

If there are lights and numbers that get triggered by goals or otherwise, it definitely would not be okay. However, even without that, zilzul Shabbos is definitely a real consideration here so it's probably best to avoid it. [Rabbi Mordechai Djavaheri goes into detail in the second half of this shiur](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/914159/rabbi-mordechai-djavaheri/berachot-on-rabbi-s-with-their-back-turned-air-hockey-on-shabbat/)

Answer (score 0):

For Sephardim, while the air hockey table could probably be left on, [it would be assur for an adult to actually play](https://itorah.com/daily-halacha/lecture/are-balls-and-games-mukse-on-shabbat/3247) :

The Bet Yosef (Siman 308) cites the Shiboleh Haleket who rules that a ball used for games is Mukse on Shabbat. The fact that it is used for playing does not render it a vessel. Moreover, it is not even fit to cover a pot, since generally it is dirty. In the Shulhan Aruch, Maran states that it is prohibited to play ball on Shabbat.

It should be noted that the Rema disagrees with this ruling.

Comment: Air hockey pucks are not generally dirty

Comment: True, @DoubleAA...but they are also a very awkward size for covering most pots with

Comment: They'd cover most cups pretty well I imagine. Pretty useful for someone makpid on gilui